# create_string_buffer and string.join error from python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a Python code from a third party which uses Python 2.7 and `create_string_buffer` and string.join on ctypes tools. I want to convert the code to Python 3.8.3, but I got an error on the following part. Here's the code after I converted it to Python3 using 2to3 tools:

```
for dev in self.devices:
        handle = libusb0.usb_open(dev)
        self.handles.append(handle) # open and store handle
        sn_char = create_string_buffer('\000'*16)
        libusb0.usb_get_string_simple(handle, offset, sn_char, 16)
        ser_num = ''.join(sn_char).split(b'\0',1)[0] # treat first null-byte as stop character
        self.sn.append(ser_num)
```

The error I got is:

```
sn_char = create_string_buffer('\000'*16)
File "C:\Python\Python383\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 65, in create_string_buffer
raise TypeError(init)

TypeError:
```

I have also already tried to make an init variable in create_string_buffer to byte (`sn_char = create_string_buffer(b'\000'*16)`, but I still got an error like this:

```
ser_num = ''.join(sn_char).split(b'\0',1)[0] # treat first null-byte as stop character
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

hope will get solution in here, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.split` and provide parameter of type `bytes`, the object you work on must be also of type `bytes`.

You can easily solve this by adding `b` before the literal string:

```
ser_num = b''.join(sn_char).split(b'\0',1)[0] # treat first null-byte as stop character
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the fast response, yea it can run, but now I get the new error at the other code which uses create_string_buffer, at this code

```
def write_data(self, sn, words_in):
    num_words = len(words_in)
    dev_num = self.sn_to_devnum(sn)
    handle = self.handles[dev_num]
    buf = create_string_buffer(b'\000'*(num_words*2-1))
    for n in range(num_words):
        buf[2*n]   = chr(words_in[n] % 0x100);
        buf[2*n+1] = chr(words_in[n] // 0x100);
    ret = libusb0.usb_bulk_write(handle, self.in_ep, buf, num_words*2,
                                self.usb_write_timeout);
    #wr_buf = [ord(buf[n]) for n in range(num_bytes)]
    #print "write buffer = ", wr_buf
    return ret;
```

The error is :

```
buf[2*n]   = chr(words_in[n] % 0x100);
TypeError: one character bytes, bytearray or integer expected
```

Sorry if my question is repeatly and too simple, cause I new in python... thanks